# C# how to insert a tab between the file name and line string. Also how to trim the string after the space

Tags: c#

I've seen a lot of answers about using Trim for whitespace, but I need to trim  everything after the first space as in " ". I'll post the section of code that I am talking about first and then below it I'll post the whole thing. I also want to know how to get a "tab" space in between the file and line variables in the same location. Here is the snippet of code I'm talking about.

```
var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(filePath, "*.FCJ", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            from line in File.ReadLines(file)
            where line.Contains(".FCM")
            select Path.GetFileName(file + line);

foreach (var f in files)
{
   lbMerges.Items.Add(f);
}
```

The variable "line" comes out as Text ~Space~ More Text. I want to eliminate the second section "More Text". I also would like to know how to get my ouput in a listview to show a tab in between the file name and the line that is read. Here is the entire code in case you need it.

```
private void rbActive_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (rbActive.Checked == true)
  {
    cbFullPath.Enabled = false;
    cbFullPath.Visible = false;
    lbMerges.Items.Clear();
    lbPCL.Items.Clear();
    string filePath = textBox1.Text;
    try
    {
      var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(filePath, "*.FCJ", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                  from line in File.ReadLines(file)
                  where line.Contains(".FCM")
                  select Path.GetFileName(file + line);

      foreach (var f in files)
      {
        lbMerges.Items.Add(f);
      }

    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException UAEx)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(UAEx.Message);
    }
    catch (PathTooLongException PathEx)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(PathEx.Message);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    cbFullPath.Enabled = true;
    cbFullPath.Visible = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: I figured out how to get rid of the excess characters on my line string. I used: 

select Path.GetFileName(file + line.Trim().Substring(0,line.Length -13));

This allowed me to Trim the Whitespace and then also Trim the last 13 characters after the string I wanted. Now I just need to know how to put a "Tab" between file and line.

Comment: Why is my question at -2? Not enough information???

Comment: People down vote because they believe you question does not show enough research -- these questions are basic and they don't see any indication of you tying to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
void Main()
{
  string test = "text some more text";

  string result = test.Substring(0,test.IndexOf(" "));

  // prints "text"
  Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

---

```
void Main()
{
  string column2 = "Put me at column 15";
  List<string> test = new List<string>() {"text some more text", 
                                          "longtext somemore text",
                                          "t some more text" };

  List<string> result = test
      .Select(s => s.Substring(0,s.IndexOf(" ")).PadRight(15) + column2)
      .ToList();

  // output 
  // text           Put me at column 15
  // longtext       Put me at column 15
  // t              Put me at column 15 
  foreach(string s in result)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Didn't see it before I came up with my partial fix. Any ideas how to put a tab in between my two strings? \t doesn't work.

Comment: `\t` works.  It is very likely that whatever is displaying the string is interpreting the tab as white-space and only displaying a single space for the tab.  I'll edit the question to show you the best way to do it.